# Problem with storage folder - getting invalid argument exception

Tags: php, laravel

I have been trying to get my home view to load for the last several hours. I have the following folders created in my storage/framework directory

```
views
sessions
cache
```

I have run the following commands in iTerm

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
composer install
```

In addition, I updated homestead and the laravel framework and I am still getting the same error. Is there some reason why this isn't working?

Here is the error

> (1/1) InvalidArgumentException Please provide a valid cache path.

EDIT 2: here's my config/app.php file

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Cache Store
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default cache connection that gets used while
    | using this caching library. This connection is used when another is
    | not explicitly specified when executing a given caching function.
    |
    | Supported: "apc", "array", "database", "file", "memcached", "redis"
    |
    */

    'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'file'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cache Stores
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define all of the cache "stores" for your application as
    | well as their drivers. You may even define multiple stores for the
    | same cache driver to group types of items stored in your caches.
    |
    */

    'stores' => [

        'apc' => [
            'driver' => 'apc',
        ],

        'array' => [
            'driver' => 'array',
        ],

        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'cache',
            'connection' => null,
        ],

        'file' => [
            'driver' => 'file',
            'path' => storage_path('framework/cache'),
        ],

        'memcached' => [
            'driver' => 'memcached',
            'persistent_id' => env('MEMCACHED_PERSISTENT_ID'),
            'sasl' => [
                env('MEMCACHED_USERNAME'),
                env('MEMCACHED_PASSWORD'),
            ],
            'options' => [
                // Memcached::OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT  => 2000,
            ],
            'servers' => [
                [
                    'host' => env('MEMCACHED_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                    'port' => env('MEMCACHED_PORT', 11211),
                    'weight' => 100,
                ],
            ],
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cache Key Prefix
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When utilizing a RAM based store such as APC or Memcached, there might
    | be other applications utilizing the same cache. So, we'll specify a
    | value to get prefixed to all our keys so we can avoid collisions.
    |
    */

    'prefix' => 'laravel',

];
```

and my .env

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:zVCAwUs7ONVbb/gWHhzDEkbBfmcNvqkCIU0tvcaGUQ4=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://bitpaigow.localhost:8000

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=paigow
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I added the error.

Comment: Please make sure the user the website is running as has access to read and write to all folders in storage/

Comment: Hmm, I've ''chmod 755'' all directories and I'm still getting that error

Comment: might be in your config... check `config/cache.php` or your `.env` for an invalid entry.

Comment: I've posted my confg/cache.php and .env file. I noticed my file driver had a path set to framework/cache/data so i changed it to framework/cache

Comment: When do you get this error?

Comment: When I load the index page of my project.

Comment: try to add this line in index.php: $app['config']['view.compiled'] = "storage/framework/cache";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception:

> InvalidArgumentException Please provide a valid cache path.

is not raised in the Laravel `Cache` but it can be found in the  `Illuminate\View\Compilers\Compiler` class, to be exact in the constructor of that class:

```php
public function __construct(Filesystem $files, $cachePath)
{
    if (! $cachePath) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Please provide a valid cache path.');
    }
...
```

So the error is raised by the `View Compiler` class that cannot find a path for the **compiled view cache**. Given the code you posted my advices are:

1. Restore the original `stores.file.path` configuration in `config/cache.php`:

```php
'path' => storage_path('framework/cache/data'),
```

2. Check that your server has the *right permissions* in the `storage/framework/views` directory: *enter, read and write*.
3. Review your `config/view.php` file, it should be something like this:

```php
<?php

return [
    /*
    */
    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views'),
    ],
    /*
    */
    'compiled' => env(
        'VIEW_COMPILED_PATH',
        realpath(storage_path('framework/views'))
    ),
];
```

4. Check in your `.env` file that you have NOT set the `VIEW_COMPILED_PATH` entry to some strange path.
5. `php artisan config:clear`
6. Last but least: `restart the HTTP server`.

Comment: After reading your answer I realize it's an error with my Homestead configuration. I am probably going to remove it and use valet from now on. Thank you